# Openlayers unable to pass innerHTML content

Tags: javascript, openlayers, parcel

I am new to OpenLayers. Have a list of images and its sequence to build full image. But does not have any coordinates.
So I created two div: one for map (as outer div) and another for displaying image table.
When map is used, page is coming blank.

Below html code:

```
<body>
    <div id="map" class="map" style="border: 1px;">
        <div id="im"> </div>
    </div>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
 </body>
```

main.js code:

```
    var imgSrc = [
    image.a0, image.a1, image.a2, image.a3, image.a4, image.a5, image.a6, image.a7, image.a8, image.a9, 
];
        var image1 = getTable();
        var map = new Map({
            layers: [
              new ImageLayer({
                source: image1
                }),
                
            ],
            target: 'map',
            view: new View({
                center: [0,0],
                zoom: 1,
                maxZoom: 8,
              }),
        });
        //---------
           // getTable();
        //document.getElementById('im').innerHTML = function(){
            function getTable(){
                var count = 0;
                document.getElementById('im').innerHTML = function(){
            function toTable(){
                var i, html = "";
                for(i=0; i<15; i++){
                    html += toTr(i);
                }
                return "<table cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>" + html +"</table>";
            }
        
            function toTr(rows){
        
                return "<tr>" + toTd() + "</tr>";
            }
        
            function toTd(){
                var i, td = "";
                for(i=0; i<10; i++){
                    var filePath = count+"_Tile_2.bmp";
                    //alert(filePath)
                    td += "<td style='border:none;'><img src=\"" + imgSrc[count] + "\" /></td>";
                    count += 1;
                }
                return td;
            }
            return toTable();
            }();
        }
```

If I call just getTable() and comment out the ol code then I am able to get the image correctly.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Looks like you have two functions named `getTable`.

Comment: @gecodezip  - one function only. one place it is defined and another placed it is called

Comment: My guess is you don't want the `<div>` with id="im" _inside_ the `<div>` with id="map" (when the map is created it will likely destroy that content).  Running the posted code, I get a javascript error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: imgSrc is not defined`.  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue, preferably a working [StackSnippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers).

Comment: @geocodezip - imgSrc is an array of images. Sure will update the above code with actual.

Comment: If you have a div inside the map div you will need some css to control how it is displayed, for example https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/examples/vector-tile-info.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just put images into the map target and expect it to work. OpenLayers will do this for you.
I made an example below where one image is divided in four parts and OpenLayers is used to display it. See the codesandbox link at the end for a working implementation.

You need to name the images according to the x/y/z positions where you want to display them. In this case I have 5 images.

```
sintel-0-0-0.png 
sintel-1-0-0.png 
sintel-1-0-1.png 
sintel-1-1-0.png
sintel-1-1-1.png
```

The first one is a lower resolution image, the other four are the complete image that has been cut up. The first number is the zoom level, then x and y position.

```
import "./styles.css";
import "ol/ol.css";
import Map from "ol/Map.js";
import TileGrid from "ol/tilegrid/TileGrid.js";
import View from "ol/View.js";
import { Projection } from "ol/proj.js";
import { Tile as TileLayer } from "ol/layer.js";
import { XYZ } from "ol/source.js";
import { getCenter } from "ol/extent.js";

const imageSize = [1920, 1080];
const extent = [0, 0, imageSize[0], imageSize[1]];
const projection = new Projection({
  code: "custom-image",
  units: "pixels",
  extent: extent
});

const layer = new TileLayer({
  source: new XYZ({
    tileGrid: new TileGrid({
      minZoom: 0,
      maxZoom: 1,
      resolutions: [2, 1],
      tileSize: [imageSize[0] / 2, imageSize[1] / 2],
      extent: extent
    }),
    url: "/data/sintel-{z}-{x}-{y}.png",
    projection: projection
  })
});

const map = new Map({
  layers: [layer],
  target: "map",
  view: new View({
    projection: projection,
    center: getCenter(extent),
    resolution: 1
  })
});
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/image-tile-grid-ufqfo?file=/src/index.js

Comment: Have checked the codesandbox, your code works there. Based on your code, I created mine and build it using parcel. Still I am getting blank page not sure why and other difference is instead of png I am using  .bmp. And each tile is having 1280x1280 size